# Using hexadecimal values in a Perl variable

Tags: perl, unix

I have a variable, `$count`, which will take a decimal value from the command line, and I have a piece of code which generates files with name `filename001 filename002 ....filename00a,filename00b` etc. It appends a hexadecimal number(without 0x) to `filename` for every new file it generates.

I use the variable `$count` to keep track of the number that is appended to `filename`. I want to pull out lines containing a particular text `Result:` from the generated file (`filename00b filename00a`, etc.). For this purpose I use the grep tool in the following way:

```
`grep "Result:" path to the file/filename0*$count`
```

This works fine till I reach the 10th file when 10 becomes `a` in hexadecimal, but `$count` in the grep command is simplified to 10, so grep is not able to find the file. I tried using `hex($count)`, but it does not seem to work. It required that `$count` variable can be incremented or decremented, and it still holds the hex value. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `hex` function in `perl` interprets its argument as a hex string and returns the corresponding integer value, for example:

```
print hex '0xAf'; # prints '175'
print hex 'aF';   # same
```

This from the definition of `hex` in `perldoc -f hex`.

It seem you want to do the opposite, convert your decimal number to a hex representation. You can do that with `printf` for example:

```
printf("%03x", 175); # prints '0af'
printf("%03x", 0xAf); # same
```

If you want to save the value in a variable, use `sprintf` instead of `printf`, it returns the string instead of printing it.

Comment: :I tried with sprintf , $count now has hexadecimal equivalent of the decimal number ,but when i try to increment it ,i get a message saying that the content in variable is a string . I would be nice if there is a method use hex numbers directly in variable .

Comment: An integer is an integer, whether you look at it in decimal form, hexadecimal or octal is a matter of formatting. Keep `$count` as a number, increment or decrement or manipulate it as you like, and when you want it formatted as hexadecimal, use `sprintf`. If you want the reverse, and get a number back from the hexadecimal _string_ then use the `hex` function of `perl`.

Comment: @Gautam You should understand the difference between a number (as a value) and its representation with symbols (usually called as digits). The count of x-es here 'xxxxx'  is `5` in decimal, and `V` in roman numeral system and `101` in binary.. when you increment (add one) to the five x-es, you get 'xxxxxx' what is `6` or `VI` or `110` - based on how you want represent it.

Comment: @janos you are right I will have to do it the way you have suggested ,thanks